# Using Divergence Theorem to evaluate the surface integral

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator, multiple-integral

This is the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTOFw.png

However, in Divergence Theorem, a double integral over the surface is equal to a triple integral over a region. And in this question, there is only one integral over a surface. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The hint is very clear. Find a vector field $F$ such that $F\cdot n=f$

Comment: I thought the F was (x^2y^2,y^2z^2,z^2x^2), let me think about it

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter your question as text instead of posting an image. Pictures are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:
$$
F={(xy^2, yz^2,zx^2) \over \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
$$

Hint 2:
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=?$$

Comment: Does sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} mean sqrt{(xy^2)^2+(yz^2)^2+(zx^2)^2} which is the unit vector?